# yii2 display image not found error

Tags: yii2

i've got a problem with displaying image I've just uploaded by imagine.

Now in my view file I have

```
<?= Html::img("@uploads/$file->hash/$file->hash-$typeThumbnail.$file->extension")  ?>
```

which correctly displays in browser

```
<img src="/home/user/projects/project/_protected/runtime/uploads/1d30a595950237c599deb4fe02750489/1d30a595950237c599deb4fe02750489-2.jpg" alt="">
```

This file exists in this directory. Also I've made 777 permission to each folder and file in project folder but still I receive 404 not found error...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have your image below your http_docs (web folder) there is no way the browser can show it like that. You have to transport it to your assets folder or something similar, or upload it to the http_docs.

Comment: Hmm, I've moved it to assets/1d30a595950237c599deb4fe02750489-2.jpg but still I can't see it src looks like "/home/user/projects/project/assets/1d30a595950237c599deb4fe02750489-2.jpg" which is correct

Comment: Okey it seems like I cant use global path here. If src looks like "../assets/1d30a595950237c599deb4fe02750489-2.jpg" image displays correctly

Comment: This is the path for upload the image, not a public url

Answer (score 0):

try use code, like this.

```
$img = yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/uploads/').$file->hash.'/'.$file->hash-$typeThumbnail.$file->extension;                 
$image = '<img src="'.$img.'" width="600" />';  

<img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/backend/web/uploads/' . $file->hash.'/'.$file->hash-$typeThumbnail.$file->extension ?>" class=" img-responsive" >
```